# how to resolve (reading 'elements') error while using FBXLoader()

Tags: three.js, loader, fbx

I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements') error and can't see my wheel and plane with a shadow texture on the floor:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
const loader = new FBXLoader();
@foreach ($files as $file)
                @if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'fbx')
                    loader.setResourcePath('storage/models/{{ $modelId }}/').load('storage/{{ $file }}', function ( object ) {
                        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                            if ( child.isMesh ) {
                                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                                    // child.material.color.setRGB (1, 0, 0);
                                    child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                                        color: 0xffffff,
                                        map: child.material.map
                                    } );
                                }
                            }
                        } );
                        object.receiveShadow = true;
                        object.castShadow = true;

                        scene.add( object );
                    } );
                @endif
@endforeach
```

here's how this car should looks like:
[image]

Comment: I think this `map: child.material.map` causing the issue. but I don't understand why and how to solve that. anyone know?

Comment: If that's the problem, why don't you load the texture separately with `THREE.TextureLoader` then assign `map: newTexture`, instead of doing the self-referential assignment?

Comment: @Marquizzo, my frined helped me to setup a server to which I load a txt with a list of direct links to the resources (fbx/png) so anything can be translated by that scheme and I don't want to ruin this. I just want to setup the material. I nearly there because all the textures and meshes work so far but look not the way I want them to look

Comment: so this is how it works right now and it looks okay: https://i.imgur.com/57irz4t.png. But I don't like it look so dark (because it's using the original material color from 3ds max) and way too shine. So, I thought it could be solved by setting up another material for every 'child'

Comment: apparently I have an array of 2 materials on each wheel: https://i.imgur.com/3OgfBFH.png. Maybe this is my problem? How to apply a Phong to each material in that case? Do I need something specific?